# I have to migrate data from one column to an other in same table but have to add a prefix in all the records. in rails DB migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am migrating records from one column to other in same table in rails, using SQL DB. I have to set a prefix with all the migrated records.

Comment: Do you need to remove the original column? To a new column or an existing?

Comment: I wanted to leave the old column as it was a reference for some other table but insert a new column with prefix+ old column records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed to migrate data from one column to another with a prefix.

```
class MigrateOldFiledata < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]

 def self.up
   execute "update table_name set new_column = concat('prefix', '/', 
   old_column)"
 end

 def self.down
 end
end
```